# This file should not be included anywhere. Usually, this means you've imported the Piral instance directly

Tags: piral

I have an Angular application as a Pilet for my Piral application. I'm trying to access a config value passed from Piral application via PageComponentProperties. As described in this page, [https://docs.piral.io/plugins/piral-ng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxO7f.png), I'm trying to access the page Component Properties ("PageComponentProps") as follows within AppModule.

```html
export class AppModule {
 @Input('Props') public props: PageComponentProps<any>;


}
```

And I'm registering the angular component as follows,

app.registerPage(`/test-location`, app.fromNg(AppModule));

I'm getting the following error, any idea?
[link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxO7f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the pilet's package.json you have the following structure:

```
"devDependencies": {
...
  "app-shell": "0.0.0" -> your version for your app-shell
...
},
"peerDependencies": {
...
  "app-shell": "*"
...
}
```